How to get a token across different Azure tenants?
My user account and My friend's API are both on the same Azure tenant(Lets say tenant A).
My user account has permission to request data from that API;I can use create a public client app and use AcquireTokenInteractive to get the token; But I would need to click on my user account in browser for token acquisition.
Now I want to develop a web host on my personal tenant(my user account is the admin of this tenant, lets say tenant B).
My initial plan is that, other end users interact with my web service host on tenant B, then my web serice use my user account's token to get data from friend's API host on tenant A.
The block is that once I publish my project on Azure, there is no way for me to do the interaction with a broswer and get the token.
I have tried to search for workarounds:

Use the refresh token. But I believe that would need at least one-time user interactive logon which is not possible for me.
Application Permissions via Admin Consent. That would need tenant B admin approval which is not possible for me at this moment.
Run the web application on my local server then use ngrok to expose to other users.

Any comments or suggestions would be highly appreicated.

Could you confirm whether you created app registration with account type as "Multi-tenant"?

@Sridevi Yes I think I can do that

Hi @YiqunCui Any update?

To get token across different tenants, make sure to create multi-tenant application with account type as below:

In this application, I exposed an API and added new custom scope named Files.Read :

Make sure to use authority as /common endpoint and select users from different tenants to login while acquiring tokens.
In my case, I used below sample python code for acquiring tokens using interactive flow:
import msal
client_id = 'appId'
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
scope = ["api://appId/Files.Read"]  # Modify scope if needed

app = msal.PublicClientApplication(client_id, authority=authority)
result = app.acquire_token_interactive(scopes=scope)

if "access_token" in result:
    print("Access Token:", result['access_token'])
else:
    print("Failed to acquire token:", result.get("error"), result.get("error_description"))

Running above code will ask the user to pick one account with /common endpoint where you can select any account from other tenants too:

After successful authentication, you will get access token in response like this:

You can decode the access token by pasting it in jwt.ms website and check the iss & tid claims to differentiate signed-in users:
Token with signed-in user from same tenant:

Token with signed-in user from different tenant:

Note that, delegated flows must have user interaction at least once while acquiring tokens and there is no other possible way.
